# Trimming the comma at the start of the string

Tags: javascript

I need your help.

I have the following function below that converts select box contents and turns them into one long string.

The problem is that there is a comma at the start once the function has been ran.

How can the existing function be modified so that I can trim/drop the comma at the start of the string

```
initial result: ,A,B,C,D,E,F

expected end result: A,B,C,D,E,F

function select2var(select) {

    var x = document.getElementById(select).options

    var values = []

    for (var i=0; i < x.length; i++) {
        values.push(x[i].value);
    }
    return values.join(",");
}

function test() {

document.getElementById('box').value = select2var('alphabet')

}
```

HTML markup:

```
<select id="alphabet">
    <option value=""></option>
    <option value="A">A</option>
    <option value="B">B</option>
    <option value="C">C</option>
    <option value="D">D</option>
    <option value="E">E</option>
    <option value="F">F</option>
</select>
```

Comment: just start with the second opt: `for(var i = 1; etc`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Don't add empty values:

```
if (x[i].value.length) {
   values.push(x[i].value)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can either not add the empty value, or -if you have multiple empty values- you can use `filter`:

```
// values = ['','A','B','','','C',...]

values = values.filter( function(v) {
  // return 'false' when v is a false-coercing value, like the empty string
  return !!v;
});

// values = ['A','B','C',...]
```

Or the shorter version (exploiting the built-in `Boolean` function)

```
values = values.filter( Boolean );
```

Comment: how about `filter(Boolean)` ;) ?

Comment: less obvious why it does what it does, but sure.